# XHR Request : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

I try to make a request to instagram to check my login / password using xhr method but I get this error message:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I'd like to know why and how I can improve my code. thank you very much.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var params = "username=username&password=password";
var CSRF_HEADER = 'X-CSRF-Token';

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

 http.open("POST", "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/", 
 true);
 http.setRequestHeader('x-csrftoken', 
 window._sharedData.config.csrf_token);
 http.setRequestHeader('x-instagram-ajax', '1');
 http.setRequestHeader('x-requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest');
 http.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
 http.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
 http.setRequestHeader("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6");
 http.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
 urlencoded");

 http.onreadystatechange = function () {
 if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status !== 200) {
   reject('error: ' + http.status);
 };
 if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
   var json = JSON.parse(http.response);
   if (!json.authenticated) {
     reject('bad password');
   } else if (json.authenticated && json.user && json.status === 'ok') 
   {
     resolve('success:', document.cookie);
   };
  };
 };

 http.send(params);
});
```

Comment: You can chain a `.catch` to your `new Promise` to handle the rejection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that message because an error was thrown inside your `Promise`'s function, or because you are hitting the `reject('bad password')` line. If you are consistently getting that error message, you can add a catch to the end of the promise like so:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

You should then get a more helpful error message.

And even if you don't consistently reproduce that error message, you should still probably add a catch anyways.

Comment: thank you very much @The Guy with The Hat :) I get this error message:    ReferenceError: window is not defined

Comment: @AmauryLeproux In a browser, `window` refers to the page's global object. Node.js doesn't have `window`, so `window._sharedData.config.csrf_token` doesn't exist. I don't know how to fix that off the top of my head, so figure it out on your own, or perhaps open another question for it.

Comment: do you have any idea how i can use it on a browser? cause now I get "window.sharedData" is not defined